# How do I balance risk and reward in a higher or lower game in order to play optimally?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, probability, probability-theory

I am trying to find out how to balance risk and reward in a higher or lower game in order to play as optimal as possible. The game I am trying to make an algorithm for is the [push your luck game on coolmathgames](https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-push-your-luck) (trying to get better at coding and problem solving) The game has a  [spinner with numbers 1-13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y40VJ.png) The goal is to get 100 points in total. You start off by spinning the wheel and landing on a number, *n*. After each spin the number that the spinner lands on gets added to a temporary score and gets removed from the spinner for the round. You then also get to choose between 4 options, bank, lower, higher, or free spin. If you bank, your temporary score gets added to your current score which is 0 at start of the game. If you choose lower or higher, the spinner spins again and depending on your choice and the new number that was picked you either lose all your temporary points and wait out the round or you can bank, pick higher or lower again, or use your free spin. I did not code the game but this should show the different conditions.

```
if choice == bank: # bank
   score += tempscore
   tempscore = 0
   newround()
elif choice == lower: # lower
   if newnumber < oldnumber:
      tempscore += newnumber
      numberslist.remove(newnumber)
      spin()
   else:
      tempscore = 0
      loseround()
elif choice == higher: # higher
   if newnumber > oldnumber:
         tempscore += newnumber
         numberslist.remove(newnumber)
         spin()
      else:
         tempscore = 0
         newround()
else: # freespin
   freespinused = True
   tempscore += newnumber
   numberslist.remove(newnumber)
   spin()
```

So far I have some data that I could use in figuring out the best move which includes

- Probability of having a higher/lower number as a percentage
- Average value of the numbers higher/lower
- Sum of all the values that are higher/lower
- How many numbers are higher/lower
- Average profit (sum of values * probability of next number being higher/lower)
- Total chance of losing (Each of the higher/lower probabilities multiplied together.)
- Free spin used
  So far I have tried just deciding with the probabilities of not losing which I think is really bad. I have also tried looking up how to balance risk and reward but I could only really find articles about what risk and reward ratios are but I could not find any way to balance them or any sort of algorithm that decides based on probability values and that is what my major problem is.
  Here is my "algorithm" so far.

```
    def CalculateChoice(self):
        if self.higherchance == .5 and self.lowerchance == .5 and self.freespinused == False:
            print('Free Spin')
        elif self.higherchance == .5 and self.lowerchance == .5:
            if self.expectedhigherchance > .5:
                if self.higheravgprofit > self.loweravgprofit:
                    print('higher')
                else:
                    print('Lower')
        elif self.expectedhigherchance > .5:
            print('higher')
        elif self.expectedlowerchance > .5:
            print('Lower')
        elif self.expectedlowerchance < .5 and self.expectedhigherchance < .5:
            print('Bank')
```

If someone could link me to an article or give me an existing solution that would be amazing! :)

Comment: Asking people to point you to the solution of a problem won't make you "get better at coding and problem solving" - the only thing that will is trying to solve the problem yourself (and probably failing a lot, but that's fine, we all did and that's what StackOverflow is here for, to help you figure out those problems). Please try to write a solution and ask a question about a specific problem you have with that solution, instead of sharing the beginnings of an attempt and asking broadly for a working solution. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should actually code the game up (without an AI) and just play it yourself. You'll get a good sense of how the game works after playing only a few times. To confirm and refine your intuition, you should then do some basic research, i.e. write a program that computes the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of choosing higher and lower after the first number is known.

Comment: Forgetting about the "free spin" for a moment, you have three options to choose from: Bank, Higher, or Lower. If you consider that you already "own" the points in the bank, then the expected reward of Bank is 0. The expected reward of Higher is (probability of success * expected points of success - probability of failure * number of points in the bank). And likewise for Lower. A good, simple, strategy, is to always choose the move with highest expected reward.

Comment: Note that choosing the move with highest expected reward is not necessarily the optimal strategy - in particular, if your opponent is closer to 100 than you, the optimal strategy is probably to take more risks; whereas if you are closer to 100 than your opponents, then the optimal strategy is probably to take fewer risks. But always choosing the move with highest expected value, regardless of the current score, is already a pretty good heuristic.